# Mensagem em inglês no fim da fila de edições sugeridas

Tags: bug, status-pronto, internacionalização

Ao analisar a última edição sugerida da fila, apareceu uma longa mensagem em inglês:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Acontece o mesmo nas [publicações de baixa qualidade](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts)

Comment: Provavelmente vale para todas as filas.

Answer (score 2):

These messages were set up for internationalization about a month ago, but have not yet been translated. I will ask the community manager of this site to consider manually translating them. If the messages are not manually translated, they will be translated automatically via our on-going process (in the next few weeks hopefully) and will then appear in Portuguese. Sorry for the delay.

Comment: Thanks for the update, Haney. Does that mean that the messages already exist on the tool Gabe uses to manage localized strings? If that's the case, the community can translate the message, and all he'd need to do is paste it there, under the proper message key.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly the situation @bfavaretto - the messages should already be in the tool.

Comment: Great, thanks! In this case, I'll post a suggested translation as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Tradução sugerida (ver a [resposta do Haney](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2026/74))

> Não tem mais nada nesta fila! Se quiser analisar mais conteúdos, [dê uma olhada nas outras filas](/review). Quer voltar às perguntas? Visite a [home do $SiteName$](/?).
>
> Quer ver o que você já analisou? [Visite seu histórico completo de análise, incluindo itens pulados](/review/$Queue$/history?userId=$UserId$).